# Get All Courier Lists in a Core PHP file

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I want to fetch all Courier List to one PHP file (External Interface).
My target is to get all courier **without using $this** object.

I am able to call magento functions to core PHP file by following code:

**File: MagentoFolder/PHPModule/index.php**

```
<?php
require_once('../app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();
// extra code 
?>
<select>
    <?php 
        // Code to Get All Shipping Courier List
    ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// Code to Get All Shipping Courier List

```
 <?php 
       $courier_list= array();
       $carriers = Mage::getsingleton("shipping/config")->getAllCarriers();
    foreach($carriers as $code => $method) {
            $courier_list[] = array(
                "title"     => Mage::getStoreConfig("carriers/$code/title"),
                );
    }
    foreach($courier_list as $item) {
        echo "<option>".$item['title']."</option>";

    }?>
```